# Accessing variable outside ajax body

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax request and I want to access an array defined in the ajax body outside its body.I am new to javascript so any help would be appriciated.This is my ajax request

```
 $.ajax({ 
             type:"GET",
             url: url , 
             success: function(finalresult) {
             arr=[]
             for(var i=0;i<finalresult.routes[0].geometry.coordinates.length;i++)
                        {
                        arr.push(finalresult.routes[0].geometry.coordinates[i])
                        global_data =arr.push

                                 }


                     }

               });
```

How can I  access array arr outside the ajax body?

Comment: just declare it outside of body, and you can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it by creating a variable outside the ajax and setting its value inside the `success` function. Also note you can get its value only after the ajax & its `success` has finished its execution. For this you can use ajax [done](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Otherwise it is always going to give an empty array

```js
let arr = [];
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  success: function(finalresult) {

    for (var i = 0; i < finalresult.routes[0].geometry.coordinates.length; i++) {
      arr.push(finalresult.routes[0].geometry.coordinates[i])
      global_data = arr.push

    }
  }
}).done(function() {
  console.log(arr)
});
```